# What is the meaning of "bad egg" here?

Tags: meaning, idioms

While I was reading the news I found a sentence

> Newcastle's Cheick Tiote responds to 'bad egg' claims

What is the meaning of **bad egg** here?

Comment: The definition of "bad egg" is found in dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

A "bad egg" is a phrase used to suggest that someone is a villain, evil, or criminal. Informally, I have heard this phrase used to describe people as troublemakers or malicious, but not necessarily criminals.

In the newsline, "Newcastle's Cheick Tiote responds to 'bad egg' claims", the author of the news article is using 'bad egg' to suggest Cheick Tiote is responding to people's claims that he is potentially *criminal or evil* as the same people claim that he had spread poison in Newcastle United's dressing room.

Answer (score 1):

"Bad egg" is an expression usually used to denote someone who is behaving in an unsportsmanlike, ungentlemanly and even dishonest way.